# Read value of a column and assign to another column

Tags: mysql, sql

MY situation is like this:

I have two tables
**TEACHERS** and **ABSENCES** each of them has a column **unitid**

I want to select the **unitid** from **TEACHERS** Table and insert into  **ABSENCES** table.

EDIT:

Can this be added into this query: ("insert into absences (student_id, date) values ('".$_GET['student_id']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");

?

Comment: Does you `ABSENCES` table already holds data? if yes, then you are looking for `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`. Also, post your table structure. by current standing your question is not clear.

Comment: absences have this columns:

 
`absence_id
student_id
date
subject
unit_session
unitid`


teachers have these:

`username  password  unitid `

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO ABSENCES(unitid) select unitid from TEACHERS
```

Comment: by the way can this be added to this query: mysql_query("insert into absences (student_id, date) values ('".$_GET['student_id']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')"); or i have to do another query ? @amit

Comment: @DiellAbazi can you add more information about TEACHERS table.

Comment: absences have this columns:  `absence_id student_id date subject unit_session unitid` teachers have these:  `username  password  unitid`

Comment: Sir i think your solution is good  too but when i do : `INSERT INTO ABSENCES(unitid) select unitid from TEACHERS` it doesnt select only one unit id it selects all unit id-s

Answer (score 0):

I tried to depict your scenario as below

Create `Absence` Table

```
create table absence (absence_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
 `date` datetime, `subject` varchar(20),
 unit_session varchar(20), unitid int);
```

Insert Data to `Absence` Table

```
insert into absence(`date`, `subject`, unit_session)
values(now(),'Math','first'),(now(),'Biology','second'),(now(),'Physics','third')
```

Create and insert data to `Teachers` table

```
create table teachers (username varchar(10), `password` varchar(10), unitid int);

insert into teachers values('abcdsed','fgdfgfdfgd',23),
('abcdced','fgdfgrtfgd',3),('harikas','fgdfgfdfgd',23);
```

At this point as you can see, `Absence` Table don't have any value for `unitid` column. it's `NULL`.

Create a temporary table as below

```
create temporary table  temptest(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
unit_id int);
```

Insert `unitid` from `Teachers` to temporary table

```
insert into temptest(unit_id) select unitid from teachers
```

Now finally, update `Absence` table by joining with temporary table like below

```
UPDATE absence a 
    JOIN temptest b 
  ON a.absence_id = b.id 
SET a.unitid = b.unit_id
```

Comment: i also think i have to do update since i only have to update the value of unitid . will try this out now

Comment: im getting an error which im not able to solve with ur method the idea is still good though

Comment: no it didnt help yet, i tried it in my mysql query and i cant fix the error that im getting , the idea is simple: to update the number of the unit id in absences table with the unit id taken from teachers table

Comment: @DiellAbazi, Forget about the previous answer and I have removed that completely. See the complete new answer. tried to implicate your scenario. Follow the steps as in answer and it will work just fine.